# Flask error 1mPOST /signUp HTTP/1.1 [0m" 400 -

Tags: python, html, flask

I'm a student, I'm trying to create an authorization page on the site. I want to link MySQL python to an html page, I found instructions on the Internet (link: [article](https://code.tutsplus.com/ru/creating-a-web-app-from-scratch-using-python-flask-and-mysql--cms-22972t)), but I came across the error presented above, it occurs when I click on the "sign up" button, communication with GPT did not give me anything(. If necessary, I can attach the zip archive itself with all the files.

all files are readable, flask writes 304, but when I click on the button it gives 400 - I found out that this is a data error, but it doesn't give me anything, I'll glue the code from below.

```
python
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def main():
    return render_template('signup.html')

@app.route('/signUp', methods=['POST'])
def signUp():
    print(request.form)
    _name = request.form['inputName']
    _email = request.form['inputEmail']
    _password = request.form['inputPassword']

    if _name and _email and _password:
        print("да")
        return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Все данные записаны !!!</span>'})
    else:
        print("нет")
        return json.dumps({'html':'<span>Вы что то пропустили :(</span>'})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

```
html

<DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>СООП</title>
        
        <script src="/static/js/jquery-3.7.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <h4 align="middle">Авторизация</h4>
        
        <p align="middle">
            <label for="inputName">Name</label>
            <input type="name" name="inputName" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" required autofocus>    <br></br>
        
            <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>   <br></br>
        
            <label for=inputPassword">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>    <br></br>

            <button id="btnSignUp" type="button">Sign in</button>
        </p>
        
    
        <script src="/static/js/btn.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I will be grateful for any help, I hope I described it in detail

if you believe the description, it should show that the data is filled in or not filled in, depending on the availability of data in the variables

There is an assumption that I did not do the ajax scripts correctly, because the article does not specify how to save and where, only the root path where to save Jquery is written and the script for the button is written

P.S.
Here is the full set of Flask text:
[31m[1mWARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment. Use a production WSGI server instead.[0m

- Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000
  [33mPress CTRL+C to quit[0m
  127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2024 14:14:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2024 14:14:58] "[36mGET /static/js/jquery-3.7.1.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 304 -
  127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2024 14:14:58] "[36mGET /static/js/btn.js HTTP/1.1[0m" 304 -
  ImmutableMultiDict([])
  127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jan/2024 14:32:45] "[31m[1mPOST /signUp HTTP/1.1[0m" 400 -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to send a *form* without sending it, your code missing a lot of things.
I will suggest you to learn a little bit about flask.

Let's break down the problem:

1. Missing form on your **html** file.
2. Missing `url_for()` to handle the submission of the **form**
3. Not handling the button click event to send the **form**.

Fix:

Make your inputs, form submitting button inside the `<form>` tag, and add `action = "{{ url_for('signUp')"}}` and make the form method `post`:

```
<form id="signup_form" action="{{url_for('signUp')}}" method="post">
    <label for="inputName">Name</label>
    <input type="name" name="inputName" id="inputName" placeholder="Name" required autofocus> <br></br>

    <label for="inputEmail">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" name="inputEmail" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus> <br></br>

    <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="inputPassword" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required> <br></br>

    <button id="btnSignUp" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Also you should add this code to be able to send the form (since you are using `button` not `input<type = "button">` which would've made the form easier to send.

```
<script>
    send = document.getElementById("#btnSignUp")
    form = document.getElementById("#signup_form")
    send.onclick(form.send())
</script>
```

Comment: Oh my gods, what a stupid mistake, and I was digging into python. Hah, thank you so much, you have no idea how glad I am to have a working code right now

Comment: You're welcome, we all learn from our mistakes.
Focus on the basics like what i said.